# Multiplying multiple tensors

Tags: tensors

Though I've managed to multiply two third-rank tensors, I can't figure out how to compute this expression in Mathematica: $$D_{ijk} = O_{il} O_{jm} O_{kn} D_{lmn}$$ where $i, j, k, l, m, n = 1, 2, 3$. Any explanation and help with the `TensorContract` methods would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) + [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract). In the following I use `o` and `d` because [`O`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/O) and [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D) are protected symbols that you shouldn't use:

```
res = TensorContract[
    TensorProduct[o, o, o, d],
    {{2,7}, {4,8}, {6,9}}
] //FullForm
```

> TensorContract[TensorProduct[o,o,o,d],List[List[2,7],List[4,8],List[6,9]]]

Here `o` and `d` don't have explicit values, and so the result is symbolic. If we assign values to `o` and `d`:

```
o = RandomInteger[1, {3, 3}];
d = RandomInteger[1, {3, 3, 3}];
```

then the tensor contraction will become explicit:

```
res
```

> {{{5, 5, 0}, {5, 6, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 2, 0}, {2, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0,
>       0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}

Comment: Just wanted to add that from my experience this procedure can be quite resource-greedy, especially for big tensors, as `TensorProduct` seems to allocate the memory for the resulting tensor first, which can be huge. There've been some workarounds with `Hold`, and using `Dot` and `Transpose` seemed to be faster still. I'm not sure if this has been fixed in newer versions of Mathematica.